# pandas dataframe columns to a single cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the dataframe:

```
df = A B l1 l2 l3
     1 1 2   3  4
     1 1 3   5  7
     1 1 1   2  9
     1 2 2   7  8
```

I want to groupby A,B , per columns, and put the values as a series in a cell.
So the output will be:

```
df = A B   l1      l2    l3
     1 1  2,3,1  3,5,2  4,7,9
     1 2   2       7      8
```

How can I do it? (efficiently)

Also, What is the solution of no ID columns?
so

```
df = l1 l2 l3
     2   3  4
     3   5  7
     1   2  9
     2   7  8
```

and the output:

```
df =  l1      l2    l3
     2,3,1,2  3,5,2,7  4,7,9,8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with lambda function with cast to strings and `join`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
print (df1)
   A  B     l1     l2     l3
0  1  1  2,3,1  3,5,2  4,7,9
1  1  2      2      7      8
```

For second:

```
df2 = df.astype(str).agg(','.join).to_frame().T
print (df2)
        l1       l2       l3
0  2,3,1,2  3,5,2,7  4,7,9,8
```

If there are strings:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg(','.join).reset_index()
df2 = df.agg(','.join).to_frame().T
```

Comment: Thanks! 
1) I get a string in the cell, What is the best way o have a pd.Series in the cell?
2) What if I dont have the columns [A,B] so no groupby is needed?

Comment: @okuoub - For both question - Is possible see in data sample what do you think ? Thanks.

Comment: I editted the post for question #2, re #1 - the type of df.iloc[0][l1] is str

Comment: @okuoub - hmmm, in second sample if no group how are specified values for join? How I know need join 1,2,3 row and not 1,2 or `1,2,3,4` ?

Comment: sorry my bad, fixed

Comment: @okuoub - answer was edited.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I have no string in the input. The output had string following ur suggestion

Comment: @okuoub - OK, then use first solutions. Before `If there are strings:`

Comment: But then I get a string... meaning I get '2,3,1' instead of a series... can you adapt it?

Comment: @okuoub - hmm, so need `pd.DataFrame([[df[c] for c in df.columns]])` for last sample data? It is possible set Series to cells, but not tsure it need it.